# Что быстрее: проверка или присваивание

Tags: производительность

Думаю, у многих была такая задача: если хоть однажды в цикле выполняется условие, то это надо отметить. Вопрос - как это сделать быстрее в плане производительности?
Так:

```
var условие_выполнено = false;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    if (условие) {
        if (условие_выполнено == false)
            условие_выполнено = true;
        ...
    }
```

Либо так:

```
var условие_выполнено = false;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    if (условие) {
        условие_выполнено = true;
        ...
    }
```

- каждый раз проверяя и 1 раз переприсваивая, либо каждый раз переприсваивать?
Предполагая, что условия достаточно тривиальные.
И еще подвопрос - на сколько % примерно эта разница, если она есть?

Comment: "как сделать быстрее в плане производительности" может сказать только конкретный тест. Но в 99.9% случаев первый вариант ничего не даст в плане производительности.

Comment: @AnT, при том, что он не поставил `break`, я бы поспорил про необходимость замеров.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Почему `break`? Очевидно `...` обозначает код, который должен выполняться много раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На примере с++, но компиляторы других языков такое тоже умеют. Запихиваем оба варианта

```
bool Check(int value);
void DoSomething1(bool flag);
void DoSomething2(bool flag);

void DoMain() {
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (Check(i)) {
            \\ if (flag == false)
            flag = true;
            DoSomething1(flag);
        }
    }
    DoSomething2(flag);
}
```

в https://godbolt.org/ с оптимизацией. 
Получаем абсолютно одинаковый код на выходе:

https://godbolt.org/z/TKujOJ и https://godbolt.org/z/GFWrwm

Компилятор всё оптимизировал. Значит вопрос исключительно в читаемости.

Comment: Благодарю, исчерпывающий ответ!

Comment: Это здорово, но всё-таки не все компиляторы могут сделать такую оптимизацию. Во всяком случае, интерпретаторы скриптов точно ничего не выкинут. А главное, код проверки или присваивания флага всё равно остаётся и выполняется на всех итерациях цикла. В моём варианте ответа после первого совпадения выполняется альтернативная ветка цикла, где таких проверок/присваиваний нет.

Comment: @Alexander_Petrow, интерпретаторы да, не умеют. Компиляторы умеют.  Break нужен не всегда по логике программы. Возможно вам нужно сделать некоторое действие для всех элементов, удовлетворяющих условию, и запомнить выполнялись ли данное действие хоть раз.

Comment: В моём примере break не прерывает цикл. Он пропускает повторную обработку последнего элемента. Цикл в любом случае выполняется для всех элементов.

Comment: @Alexander_Petrow, благодарю за уточнение про интерпретаторы - как раз мой случай. Буду думать в общем, что важнее - читаемость или производительность в моем случае

Comment: @Alexander_Pwtrow, а, да, вчитался. Но... Так поганить код ради экономии пары присваиваний это перебор.

Answer (score 0):

Производительнее подумать и добавить `break`.

А то и вообще выпилить флаг и использовать `return`.

Comment: Повторюсь ... "Вот как раз break не нужен. Нужно просто узнать, что это условие хоть 1 раз произошло. Оно может и 100 раз произойти... Вариант с проверкой "было ли условие" за циклом не рассматриваем."

Comment: @Дмитрий ну дак как раз и выйдите после первого

Comment: Зачем тут `break` и откуда вообще возникла эта идея? Этот цикл предназначен для выполнения некоей полезной работы .... С чего вы взяли, что это полезная работа должна выполняться всего один раз?

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что вариант 2 быстрее. И очевидно, что там нужен еще break; для выхода из цикла:

```
var условие_выполнено = false;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    if (условие) {
        условие_выполнено = true;
        break;

        ...
    }
```

И еще, если совсем по фен-шую, то надо писать ++i. Прединкремент легче реализуется для классов, что полезно если вдруг i станет параметром шаблона и не будет встроенным типом.

> И еще подвопрос - на сколько % примерно эта разница, если она есть?

А Вы замерьте быстродействие для обоих вариантов. Перед циклом и после цикла считайте системное время для первого варианта и для второго варианта. Только включите полную оптимизацию в компиляторе.

Comment: Вот как раз break не нужен. Нужно просто узнать, что это условие хоть 1 раз произошло. Оно может и 100 раз произойти... Вариант с проверкой "было ли условие" за циклом не рассматриваем.

Comment: @Дмитрий Зачем крутить цикл дальше, если один раз уже условие найдено? После первого присваивания Вы не получите дополнительной информации и спокойно можете прервать цикл. Это Вам ускорит Вашу программу, так как в среднем Вы будете доделывать цикл только до половины.

Comment: потому что нету задачи выйти из цикла. Там стоит многоточие и идут другие инструкции. Инструкции должны выполниться len раз...

Comment: Вопрос не как мой код переписать, а какой из 2-х вариантов быстрее. У меня и раньше была похожая ситуация, просто сейчас накипело и решил спросить и хотелось бы получить обоснованные ответ по теме. Пока только AnT высказал ответ...

Comment: "А Вы замерьте быстродействие для обоих вариантов. Перед циклом и после цикла считайте системное время для первого варианта и для второго варианта. Только включите полную оптимизацию в компиляторе." Не все умеют переключать "полные оптимизации" и тому подобные штуки. Сейчас, например, у меня такая задача на JS и рыться в получении времени в наносекундах нет никакого желания, особенно если на эту задачу существует теоретически обоснованный ответ!

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Странный вопрос. Какая разница найдено условие или нет? Этот цикл очевидно не предназначен для "поиска условия". Этот цикл предназначен для выполнения некоей полезной работы `...`. С чего вы взяли, что это полезная работа должна выполняться всего один раз? Откуда возникла идея с `break`?

Comment: @Дмитрий Если у Вас там еще есть инструкции, тогда Вам надо разбить цикл на два цикла. В первом цикле будут только проверка условия и досрочный выход. Во втором цикле будут остальные инструкции. Тогда первый цикл Вы будете выполнять в среднем половину len. Ну а второй цикл будет выполняться полностью len раз, но общее время сократится, так как первый цикл в среднем сократится.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: И в чем преимущество этого разбиения над исходным вариантом автора вопроса, где цикл всего один?

Comment: @AnT Общее время сократится, в этом и преимущество.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, 1) прогон второго цикла - загромождает код. 2) второй прогон цикла - это потенциальные len раз присваиваний переменной i новых значений, len потенциальных проверок, а не больше ли i, чем len... В моей конкретной задаче в цикле система с обратной связью, завязанном на этом условии так сказать, поэтому только 1 цикл. В топике - упрощенный пример, чтобы не забивать лишними деталями тут. Ну есть там логика своя, не туда копаете... Только один AnT меня пока понимает...

Comment: @Дмитрий Накладные расходы на цикл обычно занимают много меньше времени, чем сам цикл. В этом смысл циклов. Если же накладные расходы на цикл сравнимы со временем цикла, то вообще не надо париться об оптимизации времени.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Из-за чего оно вдруг сократится? Итераций в авторском варианте `len`. Условие нужно обязательно проверять на каждой итерации. Полезная работа выполняется для заранее предопределенного   количества элементов. Каким образом ваше разбиение может тут что-то сократить???

Comment: @pepsicoca1, вот свежий пример, что накладные расходы на цикл тоже играют роль: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50916259#50916259

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю следующую модификацию кода.

После того, как условие выполнено, дальнейшее выполнение кода происходит во внутреннем цикле. То есть `Console.WriteLine(i);` - это ваш код (у вас `...`), который нужно *продублировать*.

В этом случае происходит единственное присваивание и ни одной лишней проверки.

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var условие_выполнено = false;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == 5)
    {
        условие_выполнено = true;

        for (; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

Console.WriteLine(условие_выполнено);
```

Если заменить `5` в `if`, скажем, на `50`, вывод значений `i` останется неизменным.

Comment: Интересное решение с точки зрения производительности, возьму на заметку. В ущерб читаемости, увы, но порой оно того стоит, Благодарю!